# while the image downloaded ,it can't trigger load event in html

Tags: html, image, http, dynamic

if the bandwidth of the visitor is low, the image has been loaded seams to be suspended.

the state below is from firebug of firefox.

GET 0.jpg   200 OK  sunshopg.com   0 (305.3 KB)    1.06s

GET 1.jpg   200 OK  sunshopg.com   0 (72.7 KB)

once it becomes this,the images will never be loaded,why?